# javascript doesn't run on wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I tried fixing up the code using no conflict, but it still wont run on wordpress.

What is even weirder, the very same code runs fine on jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/egezeg/1/edit

Original code:
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wduffy/jScroll/jquery.jscroll.js

I also tested

```
$j("body").html("1234");
```

And it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What errors are you getting on the error console?

Comment: Wrap it and see if it works any better. `jQuery(function($j){ $j('body).html('1234') });`

Comment: tried but doesnt work. html() works, but the script doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add something like this to your functions.php:

```
//ad our custom Jquery
function my_init() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.2', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // load a JS file from your theme: js/theme.js
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

}
}

add_action('init', 'my_init');
```